# display notification Firebase in text view

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

I have implemented firebase cloud messaging in my app. I have been receiving messages I want to display that message in the textview of the app.

Here is the code to handle onMessageReceived..

```
public class FcmMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    private Map<String, String> data;
    private static final String TAG="MyFirebaseMsgService";
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        data=remoteMessage.getData();
        String message=data.get("message");
        String titledata=data.get("title");
        ManualNotification(titledata , message);
    }
private void ManualNotification(String title , String messageBody){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("message", messageBody);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),R.drawable.splash_img);
        Notification.BigPictureStyle bigpicture = new Notification.BigPictureStyle();
        bigpicture.bigPicture(bmp);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notifaction)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                //.setContentText(messageBody)
                .setLargeIcon(bmp)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(messageBody))
                .setContentText(messageBody).setLights(Color.YELLOW, 300, 300)
                .setVibrate(new long[] { 100, 250 })
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                .setAutoCancel(true);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `BroadcastReceiver` and receive it in Activity and show on text view . If thats what you want .

Comment: tutorial or code is possible plz

Comment: [How to use LocalBroadcastManager?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8875292/4778343)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Send a broadcast from `FcmMessagingService` whenever you need to notify the `Activity` about it .

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.push.message.received");
intent.putExtra("message", messageBody);// Add more data as per need
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

In `Activity` register a `BroadcastReceiver` to receive the event .

```
 BroadcastReceiver receiver=new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // intent will holding data show the data here 
         String message=intent.getStringExtra("message");
          tvNotificationDetails.settext(message);
        }
    };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
registerReceiver(receiver,new IntentFilter("com.push.message.received"));
}
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

`onDestroy()` is not meant to call each time So you probably unregisterReceiver in `onStop()` and register it in `onStart()`.

Comment: // intent will holding data show the data here -- !!?

Comment: textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);

Comment: I think there 's something wrong with my FcmMessagingService

Answer (score 0):

Manifest, how will look. Firebaserequired 2 service(instances and messages) another one we are using broadcast in it. so need to add anything for receiving option.